# convert the shorter forms to full forms

Tags: shell

Input file1:

```
IT  : Information Technology
B.Tech : Graduation
CS : computer science
```

Input file2:

```
B.Tech has the different groups.
One of several groups is IT and it has CS.
Most of the students are selecting these two groups.
```

oputput should be like :

substitute the fullforms of input file1 into input file2

can anyone help to create shell script using awk/sed on this...

Comment: Using sed sounds like a fine plan--as @Fredrik said, you should give it a try and show us what you've got.

Comment: Are the input and output files really just one line? I think you should insert a few newlines to make this readable and comprehendable.

Comment: awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } { for (i in array) gsub(i, array[i]) }1' master.txt file.txt

Comment: i tried the above code....its not working...

Comment: input file is not a single line....3 lines...

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -F' : ' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{for(x in a)gsub(x,a[x])}1' file1 file2
```

output would be:

```
kent$  awk -F' : ' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{for(x in a)gsub(x,a[x])}1' file1 file2
Graduation has the different groups.one of several groups is Information Technologyand it has computer science.Most of the students selecting these two groups.
```

**However** there is one problem you need to pay attention to:

recursion replace problem

for example:

```
CS : computer science (CS)
```

can this happen? how should it be done?

Comment: it will not contain shorter form of the first column in second....as you said i need to try on your example....Thanks

Comment: there is actually another **potential** problem. the replace sequence. say, `fb : Foo Bar` and 'Foo : whatever` how would you handle the `Foo` ?

Comment: not sure...i am in learning phase....trying for different options....can you please suggest for the same...

Comment: @siddi I cannot suggest, it is your requirement, you should know it exactly.